# "this" is always "undefined" in Angular 2 Validator => Angular 2 Validator is always static?

Tags: angular

It seems Angular 2 Validator has to be "static"; it can not reference any properties of the component.

Is this true? Any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: No, but you are most likely trying to refer `this` inside a function, where this is not what you expect. Share your code please, so we can tell

Comment: Share the code pelease

Comment: I wanted to reference some member variables of the component, that was I wanted to use "this" inside my Validator. If I cann't use "this", how can I access the instance variables of the component?